# Code performance for "Max Product of 3" Question

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working through some questions on Codility to improve my coding skills, I can answer most questions but the below has me confused, I can come up with a solution to get the expected answer but when I test with a really large array, it is really slow

https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/max_product_of_three/

----MY ATTEMPTED SOLUTION----

```
var sum = 0;
            for(int P=0; P<(A.Length-2); P++)
            {
                for(int Q=(P+1); Q<(A.Length-1); Q++)
                {
                    for(int R=(Q+1); R<(A.Length); R++)
                    {
                        if ((A[P] * A[Q] * A[R]) > sum)
                        sum = (A[P] * A[Q] * A[R]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return sum;
```

Comment: If all of the values in A were all non-negative, how would you solve this?  How does (possibly) having negative numbers complicate things?

Comment: Hint: The caption is _"Sorting"_

Comment: How does this produce the expected answer for *any* size array if it doesn't use the values *in* that array?

Comment: @Scott, I updated the code "sum = (A[P] * A[Q] * A[R])"

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar In fact, I wouldn't even sort it. But I guess finding a suitable sorting algorithm seems to be the goal of that lesson.

Comment: @Prasad, I thought of that, but the numbers can range from -1000 to 1000, so sorting may put large negative numbers to the other side of the array

Comment: _"sorting may put large negative numbers to the other side of the array"_ so what? Then you have the three biggest positive numbers on one side and the "biggest" three negative on the other...

Comment: I can't sort I don't think, as the questions says "(0 ≤ P < Q < R < N)"

Comment: Ok, perhaps it's my misunderstanding of the question
(0 ≤ P < Q < R < N)
To me this reads, that P is less than Q, and Q must be less than R

Comment: So I assume I have to find numbers from the array that satisfy the (0 ≤ P < Q < R < N) requirement, not just the highest numbers

Comment: The `(0 ≤ P < Q < R < N)` requirement is just another way of saying "three distinct elements".

Comment: Actually, I have to read again, but I do think it only means you cannot do `A[P]*A[Q]*A[R]` where P=Q=R. Which simply would be Max(n)³.

Comment: Ok, if it is a case that they just have to be distinct then I suppose a "sort" option could work

Comment: A little tricky is also this: _"Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

        N is an integer within the range [3..100,000]; ..."_ - So, there is one special case: N=3. No need to sort if N=3.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post my solution once I have it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "obvious" solution is to sort and compute the product of the three highest numbers and the product of the highest number and the two lowest numbers.

The answer would then be the maximum of those two products.

The reason that you need to also check the two lowest numbers is in case they are both negative, in which case their product will be positive (and may be part of the maximum product).

The fastest general sort is O(N.Log(N)), but you can do better: You can make a single pass through the array and keep a note of the three highest and two lowest numbers in the array.

(Note: The fact that the question specifies **3** as the minimum size of the array means that you don't have to account for there being less than 3 elements, which simplifies the code.)

Thus you can solve it in O(N) time like so:

```
public static int MaxProduct(params int[] array)
{
    int highest3 = int.MinValue; // Third highest.
    int highest2 = int.MinValue; // Second highest.
    int highest1 = int.MinValue; // Highest.
    int lowest2  = int.MaxValue; // Second lowest.
    int lowest1  = int.MaxValue; // Lowest.

    foreach (int n in array)
    {
        if (n > highest1)
        {
            highest3 = highest2;
            highest2 = highest1;
            highest1 = n;
        }
        else if (n > highest2)
        {
            highest3 = highest2;
            highest2 = n;
        }
        else if (n > highest3)
        {
            highest3 = n;
        }

        if (n < lowest1)
        {
            lowest2 = lowest1;
            lowest1 = n;
        }
        else if (n < lowest2)
        {
            lowest2 = n;
        }
    }

    // Answer is either the highest 3 or the lowest 2 and the highest 1
    // (because the product of two negatives is positive).

    int prodHighestOnly   = highest3 * highest2 * highest1;
    int prodHighestLowest = highest1 * lowest2  * lowest1;

    return Math.Max(prodHighestOnly, prodHighestLowest);
}
```

(Essentially the `highest1`, `highest2` and `highest3` values are being maintained in sorted order, but as discreet variables rather than in an array.)

You can call it like so: `Console.WriteLine(MaxProduct(-3, 1, 2, -2, 5, 6));`, which outputs `60`.